# Wireshark unable to capture traffic on guest OS in Virtual Box

Tags: windows

I have the following setup
Host = Windows 7
Virtual Box installed on Windows 7
Ubuntu as guest OS installed on Virtual Box.

I am starting a Openssl s_server on port 443 as SSL server on my Ubuntu guest OS and trying to connect from my host OS (Windows 7). I am having trouble capturing traffic using wireshark on guest OS. It says no network interface present.

Comment: Have you read [the docs on capturing packets](http://anonscm.debian.org/viewvc/collab-maint/ext-maint/wireshark/trunk/debian/README.Debian?view=markup)?